# Grails Spring Security plugin Access Control/Authorization without Authentication?

Tags: grails, spring-security

**My problem:**

I would love to use the Spring Security plugin's access control/authorization mechanism with my Grails application without having to use the plugin's authentication mechanism. The various Grails Spring Security plugin examples ([like this one](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/)) I've found combine these two functions. Is there an easy way to just do access control?

**Background:**

- I would like to add roles-based access control to my existing app. I would love to either just annotate my controllers or use the Config.groovy map approach for setting up the access control.
- My app already has a user domain class.
- The user domain class already handles encrypting passwords using BCrypt.
- The app does not have a "role" domain class.
- I already have controller actions, views and business logic for handling logging in and logging out. I have no interest in replacing this with the plugin's implementation.

**On the right track, but not quite helpful:**

I know this is possible to do, as explained in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322135/spring-security-authorization-without-authentication): BUT, that questions and its answers explains how to do it in a Java app using the raw Spring Security framework. I would love for someone to lay out how to do this in a way that is compatible with the latest version (1.2.7.3 as of this writing) of the Grails Spring Security plugin. I don't want to reinvent wheels that have already been taken care of by the plugin.

In addition, this [example](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html) explains how to do some of this, but it appears to be outdated because it is based on an older version of the plugin that uses Spring Security 2.x. It also only uses custom authentication for one piece of the app, while it looks like it still uses the Spring Security plugin's domain classes elsewhere.

**How to do it?**

Can someone lay out an approach for me?
I assume I need to create my Role domain class.
After that I assume it will involve custom Authentication objects and the like. But how do I hook them into use the plugin's existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own access control/authorization mechanism rather than using the Spring Security plugin. I never could figure out how to separate the plugin's authentication mechanism from the authorization mechanism. Doing the work myself was very easy.

I did the following:

- Created a new Role domain class.
- Added a Set property and hasMany relationship to my User domain class.
- Created a new AuthorizationFilters filter. This is where I put in my authorization rules. In this filter I can check to see if a user has the role necessary to access the given URL and redirect to a login page, redirect to a "not authorized page" or allow them to pass.

This doesn't have the nice syntactic sugar of the plugin and isn't quite as concise either, but it was very easy to implement and understand.

Answer (score 3):

You could go with a custom authentication provider and I have an updated version that I did as part of a recent talk. See this blog post which has a sample app and link to a video of the talk: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090

It would be simple to use a custom `UserDetailsService` - this is the most common customization done for the plugin and it so has its own chapter in the docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html

Basically you need to create a Spring Security `User` instance and Spring Security (and the plugin) doesn't care how you get the data. So your custom `UserDetailsService` just needs to be a bridge between your current auth scheme and Spring Security.

Comment: Hi @Burt Beckwith, thanks for your reply. I watched the first 15 minutes of the video, but it looked like it was mostly a deep-dive of Grails filters and Spring Security internals. No offense, but I don't really want to know more about that stuff. I am perfectly happy just to use it. Should I watch more?
With regards to the sample app, it looks like its focus is on modifying the Spring Security Plugin's methods of authenticating, not replacing it wholesale. I was having a hard time seeing what I would do the same or different than this example.
See more in the next comment...

Comment: I also read the info on the UserDetailsService before posting, but I was confused about when or why I would actually want to do this. The documentation explains how to do it, but not the use cases, situations, etc in which this would be useful. How is this applicable to my situation? Thanks!

Comment: A custom UserDetailsService is useful when you need a different approach to loading user and role data than what the plugin provides, it's as simple as that. That's why it's so common to override.

Comment: Burt, there are still a few dots that I need to have connected. I created my custom UserDetails class and UserDetailsService. I added the userDetailsService bean declaration to resources.groovy. I added my interceptUrlMap to Config.groovy. I created one protected URL (IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY) and the rest of the app is open. Now when I try to go to the protected URL, I am redirected to "/login/auth." It doesn't matter if I am logged in or not. There seem to be some assumptions that I am missing. Clearly a custom User and UserDetailsService isn't enough to do what I want. Any other tips?