# Spring security authorization without authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I have a Java JSF 2, Spring 3, Hibernate 4 Java EE Application which uses a third party library to authenticate the users. I imported the required CA certs into my JVM, added the third library to the project and configured in web.xml. The library reads the users details from smart card. This whole setup is working and users are taken to the home page by the third party library.

Here are my requirements to secure the application.

- Check one more time if the user exist in the application specific database
- Get the roles of that user from the application database
- Protect my JSF pages
- Protect my application services

I looked at this link and it seems "AuthenticationProcessingFilter" is deprecated and not applicable for Spring 3!

http://codersatwork.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/use-spring-security-for-authorization-only-not-for-authentication/

I also looked this one but I did not understand what other steps/configuration is needed.

[spring-security: authorization without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322135/spring-security-authorization-without-authentication)

I would really appreciate if someone can outline what are all the items I need to implement Spring Security with Authorization only. This is what I came up with.

1) Update pom with spring 3 security, add a filter (which filter I should pick)

2) Custom User Detail

3) Custom  DaoAuthenticationProvider

4) register this custom authentication provider in application-context.xml

5) register access decision managers for authorization

Comment: why not to take the CS from the smart card and pass it to Spring in order it checks if the user exists?

Comment: The authentication is done with a third party library, which checks the user in the company ldap.  Where as the "Check one more time if the user exist in the application specific database" is an additional check, not mandatory. It can be skipped.

Comment: How do the Smart Card and the Authentication Jar communicate? Or can it pass reliably pass a user principle to a webserver after the authentication took place, e.g via http header?

Comment: There is no web server involved. Third party authenticating library/jar is provided by another group in the company. The library is added to my app and deployed to the app server.  On accessing any page of the app, the filter of the third party is invoked and calls the authentication code in the third party library. The library then fetches the user information from smart card inserted in the card reader attached to the desktop over https. Once I am logged in (post-authentication) the app I have the user information available in the request object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base Spring Security classes suited for this use-case are  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.

In case your current authentication library results in the user being authenticated in the standard Java EE way (i.e. calls to getUserPrincipal() on HttpServletRequest instance return the authenticated user's Principal) the things you need to do should be similar to:

1. Implement interface org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService which checks that the user exists in your application database and throws UsernameNotFoundException if it doesn't
2. Add the following settings for the Spring Security:

   ```
   <!-- Declare the user details for database check -->
   <bean id="userDetails" class="com.yourpackage.DatabaseUserDetails"/>

   <!-- Default empty auth manager -->
   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>

   <!-- Use default settings from the jee namespace -->
   <security:http>
       <security:jee mappable-roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" user-service-ref="userDetails"/>
   </security:http>
   ```
3. Configure your Spring Security to perform authorization based on your requirements

The security:jee initializes both a filter and authentication provider and plugs your user-service to the provider.

In case your current authentication library doesn't use Java EE mechanisms, you will need to implement your own subclass of the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter which knows how to recognize that the user has authenticated.

You would then replace the default pre-auth filter with your own, so the configuration would look like:

```
<!-- Declare the user details for database check -->
<bean id="userDetails" class="com.yourpackage.DatabaseUserDetails"/>

<!-- Define provider -->
<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
  <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetails"/>
  </bean>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- Define alias for the authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Declare the custom filter -->
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="com.yourpackage.AuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<security:http>
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

You can find some more details in [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/preauth.html).

Comment: I am not using a JEE container, atleast for local testing. The third party library which authenticates my app add a cookie with JSESSIONID to the request header. So, how should my sping security look like?  I noticed spring-mvc used for preauthentication in the examples links I posted above. Is it required?

Comment: Your original question states that the application is Java EE built with JSF - how do you deploy it then if you don't have a JEE container? Don't you use container or application server such as Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish, JBoss, Weblogic, ...? What data does the authentication module leave in the session it creates (and identifies with JSESSIONID)? There must be some way how to load the username (or other identifier) the library authenticates. Spring-MVC is not required, you can handle whole pre-authentication processing using Spring Security only.

Comment: Thanks vschafer. I am using Tomcat not Tomcat EE for local testing. The two links I posted did use use JEE and I am not sure if the third party authentication library uses Java EE mechanisms. I will explore your suggestion "subclass of the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter". The below is what I see in the request header after it is authenticated by third party authentication library.

Comment: 'host: xyzhost                                                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0 accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5 accept-encoding: gzip, deflate cookie: JSESSIONID=D6C18D7B11A2DGDFDFDFBE; sid=ojddffdfdfdfdfdbfd0 connection: keep-alive'

Comment: The library probably leaves some content in the session (session attributes). You should consult the documentation for the library for details.

Comment: Yup. I was able to extract username from session through request in 'MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter'. But the value is lost when loadUserByUsername in CustomUserDetailsService is called. I will past the part of pom.xml, web.xml, MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and CustomUserDetailsService.java and applicationContext-security.xml here in a while.

Comment: Override method "getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request)" in your MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter  and return name of the authenticated user from it. It will then be sent to your CustomUserDetailsService.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Do I need make any extra configuration/changes to protect my business services and DAO classes, images, css and xhtml files?

Comment: It's up to you and your authorization requirements. You can find all details on how to use different authorization techniques in the Spring Security manual. Especially the URL-based authorization and expression-based authorization techniques might be of your interest, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: Thanks. I will upload the config for others.